# No module found ISBNLib using python3 and cgi

Tags: python, html, cgi

I am trying to teach myself for fun how to use cgi and run into the error "isbnlib module not found". the module is definitely installed and a similar scripts in that directory that uses isbnlib runs fine. What could be generating this error and why?

my code

```
#!/usr/bin/python3                                                                                                                                                                                                      
print("Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n")                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                                  
import cgitb                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
cgitb.enable()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
import cgi                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
import os                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
from os import system, name                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
#from googlesearch import search                                                                                                                                                                                                             
import re                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
import time                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
import random                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
from isbnlib import isbnlib                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

# Create instance of FieldStorage                                                                                                                                                                                                            
form = cgi.FieldStorage()     
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
# Get data from fields                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
gtitle = form.getvalue('Title')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

#Retrieve ISBN and metadata for the book                                                                                                                                                                                                     
isbn, meta = ibsnlib.goom(gtitle)    
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
#Extract the author and title from the metadata                                                                                                                                                                                                        
author = meta.get("Authors")                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
title = meta.get("Title")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

#make html code
html =  """                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
<title>Book Maker</title>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
<html><body>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

<h1 style='background-color:black;color:white;'>                                                                                                                                                                                             
Generating author and title from Title                                                                                                                                                                                                       

</h1>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
<p style='background-color:black;color:white;'>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

<p>ISBN: {}</p>                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
<p>Author: {}</p>                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
<p>Title: {}</p>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
</p>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
</body>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
</html>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
""".format(isbn, author, title)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
print(html)
```

Comment: Are you executing on differents environments? For example, in one code you execute as root/admin and other as common user?

Comment: I dont believe so? I dont quite understand how Cgi works but from what you are saying it seems like it may be possible that when the request is made from the browser it doesn't use admin privileges? Im not quite certain how you would fix that if so? THank you fro the help!

Comment: With some libraries on Python, when you need to execute a code that need root privileges, if you execute the code as root but you had install the library without root permission, the library isn't visible to the code... that occurred sometimes to me and after installed the library as root, the problem was solved... are you using Linux or Windows, just to know?

Comment: I am using linux

Comment: Had you tried to run `sudo pip install isbnlib`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior can be triggered if you need to run a code on an environment that need to be a root/admin and you don't have installed the library as root/admin.

So, just run `sudo pip install isbnlib` and you will get your results.